# Inflation, dark energy and symmetry breaking

Tags: cosmology, symmetry-breaking, cosmological-inflation, dark-energy, grand-unification

Aside as the inflaton has been hypothesized to have arisen from the breaking of the $SU(5)$ GUT symmetry, could dark energy have arisen as a weaker inflaton from electroweak symmetry breaking?

Answer (score 1):

It has been connected in [an article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.04359) :

> It is shown that dark energy can be obtained from the interplay of the Higgs boson and the inflaton. A key element is the realization that electroweak symmetry breaking can trigger a second phase of rolling of the inflaton, which, when provided with the appropriate couplings between the fields, can be sufficiently slow to source accelerated expansion in the late time Universe. The observed dark energy density is obtained without fine-tuning of parameters or initial conditions due to an intricate conspiracy of numbers related to inflation, gravity and electroweak physics.

Comment: Sounds to me a conspiracy theory, and the authors agree.

Comment: Anna, Thanks for the answer.  This is an important as it links inflation with dark energy with the concept of gauge invariance and symmetry breaking.  Moreover, I observed in the Wikipedia article on the Chronology of the University, the grand unification era is placed before the inflation era (it was the opposite in the old article). So it makes sense that the breaking of the grand unification led to inflation.

Comment: Moreover, when I asked this question at the Quora website, I did not get any answer. Then, I asked to a person (Professor of physics, symmetry, cosmology area) and what I got this annoying answer on a private e-mail as it is not in the main web site:  "Both SU5 GUT, and what what imagin are nothing but hypothetical imagination, where no basics scientific principles support it."  Is it ok if I give your answer to him and the Quora readers indicating that I got the answer from Physics StackExchange.

Comment: By the way, I would skeptical about Quora from now on, although some of the answers on other topics were good from another person (who yet needs to answer my question).  What do you think about that web site for general questions about Physics and cosmology? Best, Raul

Comment: This is an article I found by searching on google, because your question intrigued me. It  is obviously a research question, and one should wait  ( or search) for other similar articles, if one has the patience. You can give the link wherever you think it will help with disseminating physics information, just say "an answer in stack exchange" if you want, As fo quora, I do not participate because some of the answers are not useful, too general an "audience". (some are OK).

Comment: Yes,, send that note to quora. Moreover, the manuscript is now published in:https://doi.org/10.1007/JHEP01(2019)029

Comment: Do you mean me sending the note? I am not active there.

Comment: I meant to say that I placed in Quora a post to answer the question. Here is my post IN quora.

Comment: I meant to say that I placed in Quora a post to answer the question. Here is my post in quora:
Did not get yet a public answer here but got a private answer from some one in Quora which was basically a non-answer. However, I did find an appropriate answer in Physic Stack Exchange based on a recent published manuscript. Here is the answer:.....The Abstract  of the paper that you sent ....https://doi.org/10.1007/JHEP01(2019)029.  Although hypothetical this is important as links processes in the very early Universe. As Einstein said: Imagination is more important than knowledge.

Comment: There is no link to your quora post in your comemnts.